# Reading a file bit by bit to form a Huffman Coding Tree

Tags: bit-manipulation, huffman-code

This problem requires me to read a header from a file, that is a bit based compress file, to extract the necessary information that I need in order to form the tree. Normally the head looks as such: "1g1o01s1 01e1h01p1r0000013\n"   The 1's represents the leaf nodes and the 0's represent when we need to form a tree. There is also an extra 0 which separates the header info from the number of characters in the file. I have everything that will create the tree and print it's contents, however I am having trouble reading the information. When I execute the code one of my out puts contains a '1' in the leaf when it shouldn't. Does this mean that I am miss handling the bytes when I want to get the bits?

[image: Command line output]

> Here is the code from main:

```
while((num = ReadBit(fp, 'b')))
{
    //printf("num = %c\n", num);
    if(num == '1')
    {
        letter = ReadBit(fp, 'c');
        printf("letter = %c\n\n", letter);
        new_node = CreateNode(letter);
        Push(&Fake, new_node);
        Onecount++;
    }
    if(num == '0')
    {
        First = Pop(&Fake);
        Second = Pop(&Fake);
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(LEAF));
        new_node-> rchild = First;
        new_node-> lchild = Second;
        Push(&Fake, new_node);
        Zerocount++;
    }

    if(Onecount == Zerocount)
    {
        break;
    }

}
```

> Here is the code from the ReadBit funciton

```
int ReadBit(FILE *fp, char mode)
{  
unsigned char value;
unsigned static int count = 0;
unsigned static char letter = 0;
unsigned static char byte;
unsigned static int place;

    /* This is the bit mode, it will grab the first bit from the current byte and return it */
if(mode == 'b')
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        fread(&byte, 1, 1, fp);
    }

    value = (((byte & (1 << (7 - count))) == 0) ? '0' : '1');
    count++;
    letter = byte << count;

    if(count == 8)
    {
        count =  0;
    }

    place = 8 - count;
}

/*This is "character" mode. It will grab enough bits in order to create a byte that will be a letter */
if(mode == 'c')
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        fread(&letter, 1, 1, fp);
    }
    else
    {
        /* This will read in a new byte and add in as many bits as we need to complete a byte from the previously saved bits */
        fread(&byte, 1, 1, fp);
        value = letter + (byte >> place);
    }
}

return(value);
 }
```

Comment: If you need more info just let me know. I really want to understand where the 1 is coming from. I also appreciate all input in advance.